# python cut portion of video "Fastest way"

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut out portion of video file using python(3.7.1) and ffmpeg in my flask (1.0.2) application,
this is solution 1

```
    # solution 1
    from moviepy.editor import *
    from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip

    video = VideoFileClip('/app/videos/video.mkv'.subclip(10, 20)
    video.write_videofile('/app/videos/cutted_video.mp4')
```

and here is result in flower panel screenshot.
as you can see cutting out two videos takes more than two seconds.
[image]
and this is solution 2

```
    # solution 2
    from moviepy.editor import *
    from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip


    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(
        '/app/videos/video.mkv',
        10,
        20,
        '/app/videos/cutted_video.mp4'
    )
```

first solution works pretty well, but It takes about 1-2 seconds to cut the video out.
instead second solution works very fast ( less than 0.5 sec ) but the output video is just audio plus black screen.

what is the fastest way to cut portion of video in python.
If there is any other library which is faster please tell me that.

Comment: I suggest every person who wants to down vote the question for any reason, at least put a comment if there is anything wrong with the question,
just to let the writer know.

Comment: also consider that probably the slowness is not result of using a specific tool, but It's result of your computation capacity.

Comment: my server is good enough I check that out before, thanks !

Comment: so checkout the extra configs in `to_videofile`, maybe that helps.

Comment: I'll check it. thanks

Comment: @mhndev I can't recreate this problem. The second option works fine for me, though admittedly I was doing mp4 to mp4 rather than mkv to mp4. Perhaps converting the video first works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this method and It's pretty fast:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("sample.mp4").subclip(start, end)
clip.to_videofile(outputfile, codec="libx264", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, audio_codec='aac')
```

Comment: i tried your specified options cutting two videos takes more than 2 seconds.
I will put the screenshot in my question.

Comment: If you are trying to do something like [this](https://github.com/antiboredom/videogrep), you can go through It's source code.

Comment: yes thats what I'm doing , is it quick enough? I;m already doing the search using elasticsearch

Comment: I've used it myself and It does the job pretty well.

Comment: @mhndev Also check out [this](https://github.com/open-source-ideas/open-source-ideas/issues/88). you'll find some valuable ideas here.